# how to insert array of objects and array of nested objects into mongodb using mongoose in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I understand there are similar questions already available but all of those questions talks about only array of nested objects but my query is array of objects and each object in array contains nested objects. So other questions are not helpful for me in this case.

My query is I want to insert below data into mongodb using mongoose in nodejs.

My JSON looks like below

```
{"categories": [
    {
        "name": "Books & Magazines", 
        "value": 1,
        "subCategories":[
            {
                "name": "Book", 
                "value": 1,
            },
            {
                "name": "Book series", 
                "value": 2,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Books & Magazines", 
        "value": 2,
        "subCategories":[
            {
                "name": "Book", 
                "value": 1,
            },
            {
                "name": "Book series", 
                "value": 2,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Books & Magazines", 
        "value": 3,
        "subCategories":[
            {
                "name": "Book", 
                "value": 1,
            },
            {
                "name": "Book series", 
                "value": 2,
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

My schema for this JSON looks like below

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
      categories:[{
        name: {
          type: String, 
          required: true, 
          trim: true
        },
        value: {
          type: Number, 
          required: true
        },
        createdAt: {
          type: Date, 
          default: Date.now
        },
        updatedAt: {
          type: Date, 
          default: Date.now
        },
        subCategories:  [{
          name: {
            type: String, 
            required: true, 
            trim: true
          },
          value: {
            type: Number, 
            required: true
          }
        }] 
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Page_Categories', CategorySchema);
```

Controller part below

```
const Page_Categories = require('../models/categories');

exports.savePageCategories = function (req, res, next) {
    const data = req.body;
    // console.log("Data: ", data.categories)
    const pageCategories = new Page_Categories({ data });
console.log("pageCategories: ", pageCategories)
    pageCategories.save((err, post) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      res.status(201).json({
        user: post
      });
    });
};
```

I am able to successfully save but it saves as empty record. Please see below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5ae9e7855059417c471784"), "categories" : [ ], "__v" : 
0 }
```

Any idea why it inserts empty record?

Comment: Did you try specifying a type for your SubCategories prop?: `[{type: SubCategories}]`. If So are required, you can also set that with `required: true`.

Comment: Updated my schema as you suggested. Can you also tell me how to set that request json to PageCategories schema in controller? this is wr I feel difficulty.

Comment: Assuming your request data is in `req.body.data`, try to pass your `data` const to the pageCategories instantiation: `new pageCategories(data)`.

Comment: I tried but it is failing with validations. ValidationError: Page_Categories validation failed: value: Path `value` is required., name: Path `name` is required

Comment: Would you mind updating the original code to refelect exactly what your controller and schema look like?

Comment: Its already there in my question. its original schema and controller part too

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized. Try removing the `.add` part: `CategorySchema.add(`... and changing `SubCategories: {type: SubCategories, required: true}` in your `CategorySchema` to this: `SubCategories: [{type: SubCategories, required: true}]`.

Comment: One more thing: in your JSON, `subCategories` is using camel case, but in your CategorySchema, you are doing: `SubCategories`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163121/discussion-between-hemadri-dasari-and-marventus).

Comment: It looks like this question was changed at some point into an answer. Needless to say, that is confusing, so I have rolled it back to a position where it was still a question.

Answer (score 0):

Help from @Marventus resolved the issue.

If you look at my json (it's in my question) it is actually an array of categories and each category has its own sub category which is also an array. So if you look at below schema I had declared name, value, createdAt, updatedAt as a normal object instead of an array. Which was failing with validations.

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String, 
      required: true, 
      trim: true
    },
    value: {
      type: Number, 
      required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date, 
      default: Date.now
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Date, 
      default: Date.now
    },
    subCategories:  [{
      name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        trim: true
      },
      value: {
        type: Number, 
        required: true
      } 
    }]
})
```

Working schema: I have changed top level categories to an array and it worked

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
      categories:[{
        name: {
          type: String, 
          required: true, 
          trim: true
        },
        value: {
          type: Number, 
          required: true
        },
        createdAt: {
          type: Date, 
          default: Date.now
        },
        updatedAt: {
          type: Date, 
          default: Date.now
        },
        subCategories:  [{
          name: {
            type: String, 
            required: true, 
            trim: true
          },
          value: {
            type: Number, 
            required: true
          }
        }] 
    }]
})
```

Comment: post the solution in answer.

Comment: Updated the answer